# pagerfanta submit with the form data

Tags: symfony, twig, pagerfanta

I have a form with criterias that return a list of results in the same view adding the PagerFanta paginator. To go to next page or previous page I need send the same form data (criterias).

What is the better way?

Thank you and I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: have you tried to goole this issue?

Comment: Yes, I have searched in differents forms.

Comment: can you please provide some code for this, I am not familiar with the PagerFanta or Symfony2 or twig, but I am sure that anyone that is going to help you fix this will need more information about the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with this approach:

When I render the view of twig I Always fill the form with the data of previous post...

With this javascript code I get the expected result

```
$('.pagination ul > li > a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#form_name').attr('action', this.href);
  $('#form_name').submit();
});
```